# Seemingly irregular #NUM! error in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm running a financial model in Excel, for the purpose of generating multiple IRR scenarios. However, I'm running into trouble with the #NUM! error, and having checked common causes for this, I am none the wiser.

Both examples have one positive cash flow item.

**Example with #NUM! error**

[image]

---

**Working Example**
[image]

Any suggestions for what the root of the error might be? The error seems to be rather irregular as both higher and lower model inputs return a valid IRR.

Comment: Did you evaluate the function step by step to see at what stage you're getting the error? What formula are you using?

Comment: I have, and the since i'm only really using the following formula `=IRR(C34:AB34)` it doesn't return any calculation steps. I have played around with it a bit more and found that adding a guess value of -99% does solve the majority of my issues for a range of scenarios. Still not sure I understand what happens or why it needs a seed value.

Comment: Did you just have a view what's in those cells in both cases?

Comment: My understanding is that the `#NUM!` error is returned because the actual IRR is not close enough to the assumed guess of 10%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ron Rosenfeld is correct.  See [this Microsoft link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/How-to-correct-a-NUM-error-f5193bfc-4400-43f4-88c4-8e1dcca0428b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1).

IRR uses an iterative formula and limits the number of iterations.  It returns the #NUM! error if it can't find a solution within that number of iterations.  The fix is to provide a better value for the guess.

You can also change the setting for the maximum number of iterations.  From the link above:

[image]

Comment: iterative method examples -> https://www.google.se/search?q=newton+raphson+method+example